# List view row Selection

Tags: android, listview, select, listviewitem

i have a simple list view control 
my queries are:

1) how to set first row selected on start (after fill data in list view)

2) when i navigate by hardware button i got AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and color of row background change, but when i click i not get any OnItemSelectedListener and no row selected. How to select row on click.

3) when i change focus list row selection removed,

please any one with any solution, code example or articles 
i search but no susses

with regards
Chandra Kant Singh

Answer (score 1):

> how to set first row selected on start
>   (after fill data in list view)

Call `setSelection()` on the `ListView`. However, this only will have a visual effect if the user entered your activity via the pointing device (trackball, D-pad, etc.).

> How to select row on click.

You don't.

> when i change focus list row selection
>   removed,

If I understand what you mean by "change focus", this is working as designed.

Please review [this article on touch mode](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html) and the use of the "selected" state, then adjust your UI design to follow Android conventions. Selection is only used when the user navigates with the pointing device, not when the user uses the touch screen.

Comment: setSelection() does not have the required visual effect as you say. Then how can the item be highlighted to the user in other cases? Is there no way this can be achieved?